# Creating and exposing a web service in MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I've looked around for some tutorials, but everything I see is how to use REST services with my app. But that's not really what I need, I'm not doing basic GET requests, the end user needs to do some complicated calculations with several classes and variables from my web service.

In a Web Forms app, I would just add a Web Services solution and do everything in there. Is that the recommended solution for an MVC app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an asp.net mvc application also have a web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788103/can-an-asp-net-mvc-application-also-have-a-web-service)

Comment: Use WCF. It's the replacement for what you're thinking of as "web services".

Answer (score 0):

.asmx, WCF, MVC are just integration points.  Its not like one of them can't interact with complicated calculations with several classes and variables.

Comment: how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Shiv Kumar - I don't think its a valid question.  There is no difference between MVC and WebForms when it comes to interacting with physically separated services.

Answer (score 0):

While there's nothing stopping you from adding a WCF or any other kind of traditional web service to your web application, I think you should take another look at using a pure MVC rest style approach.

The complications of how the data is being used (especially on the client end) don't really matter to rest.  You can accept just as many variables, and do just the same calculations with a pure MVC REST approach as you can with WCF.  It's all in how you represent the data in your service.

MVC also does a fantastic job of model binding properties sent in either via query or POST parameters and mapping them to complex objects on your actions, making it fairly easy to deal withy our data the way you want to on your end.

The largest disadvantage to just running WCF separately is that it's another resource running on your webserver.  If you can use MVC for both your application, and the "service" it exposes, your webserver will thank you.